# JavaScript: async function that would retry for a period of time at a given interval

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write an `async` function that is going to `await` a function that got passed as one parameter and I wanted this `async` function to retry this operation for **5 mins** every **10 seconds**.

I found one function that sort of does this but it retries based on the numbers of times instead.

```js
async function retry(fn, n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    try {
      const ret = await fn();
      if(!ret) throw new Error() // if `ret` is null or undefined, we will retry.
      return ret
    } catch {}
  }

  throw new Error(`Failed retrying ${n} times`);
}
```

Is there a way to tweak this function to satisfy my use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function is async, you can easily create timeouts to wait between subsequent calls:

```
const sleep = t => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t))
async function retry(fn) {
  const startTime = Date.now()
  while(Date.now() - startTime < 5 * 60 * 1000) {
    try {
      const ret = await fn();
      if(ret) 
        return ret
      // if `ret` is null or undefined, we won't return.
    } catch {}
    await sleep(10 * 1000)
  }

  throw new Error(`Failed retrying`);
}
```